# Page Load Slow Due to JS Issues

Tags: civimember

I am using CiviCRM 4.7.3 on Joomla 3.4.8. I have noticed when going to the user dashboard that it is taking 30-45 secs to load that page. All other pages are loading in less than 3 secs. To explore the issue, I used Firefox with FireBug to see the Net loading. I found that nearly 50 items are listed as shown in the picture. These items only show when going to a CiviCRM related page.  Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. I needed to manually set the URL Resources paths. Although it had the variable set during setup, it was not the absolute path.