# Contribution page loading slowly

Tags: contribution-page

Each year we sign members up for our organization. Have been using civicrm for 6 years. Past 3 with PayPal. This year the contribution page loads very slowly. Browser circle spins one way then the other. Current on Joomla and civicrm. Joomla 3.5.1  CivCRM 4.7.7 PHP 5.4.43 mysql 5.5.31  isfpta.org is the site.  https://www.isfpta.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&view=Contributions&task=civicrm/contribute/transact&id=14&reset=1&Itemid=1954 is the page.  Earlier in the year Feb/Mar we didn't have this problem.  I ran the browser inspector and did a performance trace.  I hoped for a single or several items that were taking along time but only found many little items.  I am not able to ascertain from the trace any smoking gun.

From clicking on the joomla menu item, a civicrm contribution page, it will take upwards of 10 seconds for the page to load at times.  The browser wheel spins one way and then spins the other.
I have a separate issue that I assume is unrelated, [Paypal Standard return update not completing](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11828/paypal-standard-return-update-not-completing)

Comment: Can you add some more information like your hosting platform, version of civicrm etc. Can you use a browser 'inspector' to ascertain what part of the process is running so slowly. Is this a public page, if so you could share the link and others might do the inspecting for you.

Comment: @petednz added more details any further assistance you can provide appreciated

Comment: want to add what 'slow' is looking like to you in seconds?

Comment: also random and perhaps unwanted thought, looking at what you are trying to achieve, have you considered a drupal frontend to civicrm so you can capture all the various relationships via a webform and hence have 1 record for a mother who may have several kids at the school

Comment: This did the trick http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10320/page-load-slow-due-to-js-issues  I needed to manually set the resources url.